# Hash map with long values

Tags: java

I would like to create a hash map that maps an object of type `Element` to `long` values. What I have done so far:

```
class Element {
  public int x;
  public int y;
}
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    HashMap<Element, Integer> marks = new HashMap<Element, Integer>();
    Element e = new Element();
  }
}
```

From what I saw `Integer` is a wrapper that converts an `int` to an `Object` of `int` type. How could I do the same for `long`?

Comment: `Long` is the wrapper type for `long`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How could I do the same for `long`?

All primitives have corresponding wrapper classes:

```
Primitive type  Wrapper class
boolean         Boolean
byte            Byte
char            Character
float           Float
int             Integer
long            Long
short           Short
double          Double
```

From [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Long`, which is the object (wrapper) version of long.  Java automatically handles this conversion for you with autoboxing.

See docs for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this would be to use [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) library. Using and storing small objects (like in your case) in standard java containers may be inefficient. This library addresses this problem by providing separate container implementations for all primitive types.

In your case you can use [Object2LongOpenHashMap](http://javadox.com/it.unimi.dsi/fastutil/6.5.2/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/Object2LongOpenHashMap.html).

Even better, because your keys are only 8 bytes long, you can fuse `x` and `y` into single long primitive and use [Long2LongOpenHashMap](http://javadox.com/it.unimi.dsi/fastutil/6.5.2/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/longs/Long2LongOpenHashMap.html) (or Long2LongArrayMap). Something like this:

```
void put(Long2LongOpenHashMap map, Element key, long value) {
  long k = ((long)key.x << 32) | key.y;
  map.put(k, value);
}
```